# Cannot get cmake to link to GLFW library

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake, glfw

I am trying to write an OpenGL application with GLFW. The file structure is as follows

```
-USG
 -build
 -include
   -glfw-3.3
 -src
   -CMakeLists.txt
   -main.cpp
 -CMakeLists.txt
```

The CMake in the `USG` file is as follows.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(USG)

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Set GLFW variables
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
set(GLFW_BUILD_DOCS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_TESTS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Add subdirectories
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
add_subdirectory(include/glfw-3.3)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

And the CMakeLists in the `src` file is as follows

```
add_executable(usg main.cpp)

set(OpenGL_GL_PREFERENCE GLVND)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

if (OPENGL_FOUND)
    target_include_directories(usg PUBLIC ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR})
    target_link_libraries(usg ${OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY})
endif()

target_link_libraries(usg glfw)
```

I run `cmake ../` followed by `make` in the build folder. Running cmake runs as expected. Running make builds glfw fine but when it gets to main.cpp it fails at `#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>` telling me `GLFW\glfw3.h: No such file or directory`. It seems to me like the cmake isn't properly linking the header file to the main.cpp file, but I don't know enough about cmake to get that to work. I've tried looking through the examples provided in the glfw-3.3 example folder but I couldn't make enough sense of it to solve my problem. I've tried drawing what knowledge I could from the many similar problems on stack overflow but none of them could help.

I'm following [this tutorial here](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build_guide.html). I want the OpenGL application to be relatively portable, which is why I'm compiling glfw from source rather than using a binary. I'm building on Linux, if that matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>` instead of `#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>`

Backslashes in include paths are a bad (Windows)-practice and do not work with GCC.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Syntax.html